# Play store message "this item isn't available"

Tags: android, google-play, app-distribution

I uploaded my app about two weeks ago and at first, after it was approved it just said it wasn't available on my devices which I understand is a compatibility issue, and was fixing it. But when I checked it a couple of days ago, it says it is not available.
I can't find anything similar to this that can help.
please if you have sources that may help or can help yourself I would appreciate it.
[this is what it shows on the store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUg6w.jpg)

Edit:
[these are the apps in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjb2z.png)

Comment: That does it say on the Google Play console? Can you show the status of the app and country availability?

Comment: So on you console it shows that the app is in open testing, but have you enrolled for it on the device?

Comment: Apparently not. this is my first tme using the console with this new interface so i must've missed it. i uploaded the apk for the testing and thought that was it.    thanks for the help and bringing that to my attention. Now it says the status is production and its in review.

Comment: Once it is reviewed, you should be able to download the app

Comment: @user14678216 I get the same problem in my app. how long it takes to publish.

Comment: For updates recently, I usually find it to be a day or two, sometimes may take longer